# How does social plugin work?

Tags: javascript

**Introduction**

I am planning to create a widget much like, Facebook provides for *likes*, *share* etc. Basically the requirement is:

1. The client will include JavaScript provided by us.
2. The client can, now, put our widgets in the page having the JS. The widget placeholder looks like `<nw:fav id="911"/>`.
3. When page gets loaded, the JavaScript replaces the placeholders with actual HTML. The JavaScript also keeps this DIV updated with dynamic (perhaps using [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling)) content.

**Problem**

I am not sure how to do step #2.

1. How JavaScript will get all the `<nw:...` tags and all the attributes of it?
2. How to replace the tag with real HTML tag?

**Constraints**

1. I am trying to avoid JQuery or any other JS library, since we may cause conflict if the client is also using JQuery, may be some other version.
2. I don't really want to use IFrame.

---

I am looking for approaches. Open for suggestions.

Comment: What browsers do you aim to support?

Comment: @Bryan Downing Ideally all including IE6 :). So, IE6+, FF3+, Safari2+. But in worst case scenario we may exclude only IE6. However, I see Facebook tags like `<fb:likes..` working everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facebook connect JS SDK is open source.  You might find the xfbml.js file useful.  See [this link](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/src/xfbml/xfbml.js).

Basically when the document loads, the code walks the dom looking for elements that have a specific namespace (FB uses fb, you appear to want to use nw).  Find those elements and then replace them with whatever content you need.

Comment: Awesome! Just learned about `document.getElementsByTagNameNS`.